# How to bring JSON file via URL in Django?

Tags: json, django, django-forms

I am new to Django.  I have a few independent dropdown boxes. Now I have to get data from the backend in JSON and parse it for each dropdown boxes. How do I do this? How do I bring JSON  via URL? how should I make use of Ajax methods here?
Basically, I want to use Ajax method calls and JSON bind data to ui.

Comment: Have you consider using a library to do this ? Like django-select2 : https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Nope.I will surely try it out. Thank you. Apart from this what more can I do?

Comment: Your question is a bit too general. Maybe if you provide some code you already tried and complete your question to be more specific, I could help you but now the only thing I can suggest you is to look on the internet to find a tutorial on __Django Ajax__

Comment: I actually have 6 dropdowns in forms.py I haven't done anything in the models.py file. What I want is that these dropdown should be parsed with ajaxcall.